# Stop a batch command if it doesn't terminate in a given period of time

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple batch file, which runs a bunch of PHP files, one after the other. Sometimes, some of these php files hangs, and when this happens, the whole batch file stops from executing the files that are comming after this.

Is there a way, to stop running the command, and proceed to the next command after a given period of time, in a batch script?

My batch file only consists till now around 800 lines with command simmilar to the ones below:

```
php72 ../simulation.php --version 0.9.0.4 --hashsimmilar false --thinkahead 0 --detailed 0 --outfile catacombs.outfile.csv --workingdir "C:/xampp/htdocs/rpg_prog/" --customfight 1,2,,,,1,,,1,,0,0,0,Catacombs1
php72 ../simulation.php --version 0.9.0.4 --hashsimmilar false --thinkahead 1 --detailed 0 --outfile catacombs.outfile.csv --workingdir "C:/xampp/htdocs/rpg_prog/" --customfight 1,2,,,,1,,,1,,0,0,0,Catacombs1
php72 ../simulation.php --version 0.9.0.4 --hashsimmilar false --thinkahead 2 --detailed 0 --outfile catacombs.outfile.csv --workingdir "C:/xampp/htdocs/rpg_prog/" --customfight 1,2,,,,1,,,1,,0,0,0,Catacombs1
```

If for example, the second line in the above list hangs, the whole batch file will hang, and the third line will never be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given there are not any other `php72.exe` processes, you could prefix each `php72` call by `start "" /B` and put after each `php72` call the following lines (remove the `/F` option if you do not want to kill the tasks forcefully):

```cmd
timeout /T 10 /NOBREAK > nul
taskkill /IM "php72.exe" /F > nul 2>&1
```

The `>` suffixes just avoid any (error) messages to be thrown.

---

To not have to copy the above lines multiple times, you could also place the following code on top of your batch file:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Read all lines from this batch file that begin with `php72 ` and iterate over them:
for /F "delims=" %%C in ('
    findstr /BIC:"php72 " "%~f0"
') do (
    rem // Execute the currently iterated `php72` command line:
    start "" /B %%C
    rem // Wait for some time:
    timeout /T 10 /NOBREAK > nul
    rem // Kill the `php72` process (or actually all of them) if still running:
    taskkill /IM "php72.exe" /F > nul 2>&1
)
rem // Avoid to fall into the `php72` command lines another time:
exit /B

rem // These are your lines:
php72 ../simulation.php --version 0.9.0.4 --hashsimmilar false --thinkahead 0 --detailed 0 --outfile catacombs.outfile.csv --workingdir "C:/xampp/htdocs/rpg_prog/" --customfight 1,2,,,,1,,,1,,0,0,0,Catacombs1
php72 ../simulation.php --version 0.9.0.4 --hashsimmilar false --thinkahead 1 --detailed 0 --outfile catacombs.outfile.csv --workingdir "C:/xampp/htdocs/rpg_prog/" --customfight 1,2,,,,1,,,1,,0,0,0,Catacombs1
php72 ../simulation.php --version 0.9.0.4 --hashsimmilar false --thinkahead 2 --detailed 0 --outfile catacombs.outfile.csv --workingdir "C:/xampp/htdocs/rpg_prog/" --customfight 1,2,,,,1,,,1,,0,0,0,Catacombs1
```

Of course you can have the `php72` command lines in a separate file, then the `for /F` loop needs to be adapted accordingly:

```cmd
rem // Specify appropriate text file:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%C in ("D:\path\to\file.txt") do (
    rem // Same loop body as above...
)
```

Comment: My problem is that, the timeout function will only be called, if the php72 line executes and terminates correctly. Thus the code will never reach that point in my case.:(

Comment: In the meanwhile, I stumbled upon start myself:) Thanks for the help!