# Can't figure out what's causing the error in this batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch file

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem // Read all lines from this batch file that begin with `php72 ` and iterate over them:
for /F "delims=" %%C in ('
    findstr /BIC:"php72 " "%~f0"
') do (
    rem // Execute the currently iterated `php72` command line:
    start %%C

    SET checktasklist=true
    FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,30) DO (
        FOR /F %%x IN ('IF "!checktasklist!" == "true" tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq php72.exe"') DO (
            IF "%%x" == "php72.exe" (
                timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL
            ) ELSE (
                SET checktasklist=false
            )
        )
    )
    taskkill /IM "php72.exe" /F > nul 2>&1
)
rem // Avoid to fall into the `php72` command lines another time:
exit /B

php72 ../simulation.php --version 0.9.0.4 --hashsimmilar false --thinkahead 0 --detailed 0 --outfile catacombs.outfile.csv --workingdir "C:/xampp/htdocs/rpg_prog/" --customfight 1,2,,,,1,,,1,,0,0,0,Catacombs1
php72 ../simulation.php --version 0.9.0.4 --hashsimmilar false --thinkahead 1 --detailed 0 --outfile catacombs.outfile.csv --workingdir "C:/xampp/htdocs/rpg_prog/" --customfight 1,2,,,,1,,,1,,0,0,0,Catacombs1
php72 ../simulation.php --version 0.9.0.4 --hashsimmilar false --thinkahead 2 --detailed 0 --outfile catacombs.outfile.csv --workingdir "C:/xampp/htdocs/rpg_prog/" --customfight 1,2,,,,1,,,1,,0,0,0,Catacombs1
.... continued with 190 lines of more simmilar lines like the above
```

What I am trying to do in this batch file, is to run each `php72.exe ...` commands, wait for 30 seconds, but only if they are still running, and if they still run after 30 seconds, terminate them, and go to the next `php72.exe ...` line.

I've managed to achieve this, but most of the time, a `php72.exe` file will run in around 0.8 seconds, yet I still perform the `tasklist /NH...` command 30 times, and this slows things down. That's why I wanted to put a local variable inside, that if the task wasn't running after an iteration, I don't have to retest it again the remaining amount of iterations.

Right now, I am getting `"true" was unexpected at this time.` this error. I don't understand why this is happening, or how could I achieve my desired behaviour. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hm... I know this script... ;-) Try with `^=^=` instead of `==`; since you are using the `if` condition within `for /F`, unescaped `==` become lost...

Comment: @aschipfl yes, most of it is your doing:) and the above comment works flawlessly, add it as an answer please, so I can accept it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the portion `IF "!checktasklist!" == "true"`: since it appears within `for /F`, unescaped `=`-signs become converted to spaces, so you need to escape them, like this:

```cmd
        ...
        FOR /F %%x IN ('IF "!checktasklist!" ^=^= "true" ...') DO (
        ...
```

You could also change the FALSE value of the flag variable `checktasklist` to be empty and simply use `if defined` instead:

```cmd
    ...
    SET "checktasklist=true"
    FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,30) DO (
        FOR /F %%x IN ('if defined checktasklist tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq php72.exe"') DO (
            IF "%%x" == "php72.exe" (
                timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL
            ) ELSE (
                SET "checktasklist="
            )
        )
    )
    ...
```

---

A totally different approach, based on the [original script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54543883):

What about replacing the line:

```cmd
start "" /B %%C
```

by this one:

```cmd
start "" /B cmd /C %%C ^& taskkill /IM "timeout.exe" /F ^> nul 2^>^&1
```

This should terminate the `timeout` process(-es) after having completed each `php72` process.

Comment: I just stumbled over this post again and found an even easier solution related to your failing `if` condition: moving it out from the `in` clause of the `for /F` loop, like this: `IF "!checktasklist!" == "true" FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist ...') DO ( ... )`, or `if defined checktasklist FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist ...') DO ( ... )`